# How compare two binary files, showing long portions that match?

Tags: diff, binary, file-comparison

I have two pcapng files, and I'd like to compare them showing the matching portions and not. Basically, I know that in these 2 files each block header is different, but the block data are the same.

[image]
As you can see, the portion I've circled are the same. I'd like some CLI command to show the parts that matches, no matter the offset. Hope that I'm clear enough, and sorry for my english.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: How would you want the output to look like? Maybe you can convert both files to hexdumps and compare these as text files.

Comment: See [How do I compare binary files in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/125376/how-do-i-compare-binary-files-in-linux)

Comment: I added a picture to make you understand what I'd like to have. I used Hexinator, I can't find a way to use a comparison tool to point out those common parts

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried VBinDIFF ..? It's a CLI application you can download with brew ...

brew install vbindiff

I'm having the same issue: MASSIVE, global differences after changing ONE character on 8MB files ..? I'd just like to better understand it myself. Thx.